# placing a view right behind my tab bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uitabbar, controllers

I have a tab bar with 3 buttons, each of which loads a different controller and hence a different view.
I would like to place a UIView right behind my tab bar so that it is visible on all 3 different sub-controllers.

How can I achieve that?
[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: what is the use of adding view behind tab bar?

Comment: edit your question to make it more clear. we are not getting what u want to do?

Comment: edited: so that the green image would be there no matter which button is pressed

Comment: @Ted : please accept an answer if your problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy (this is using a storyboard) :

• Create a subclass of `UITabBarController` (I'll call it "`TabViewController`").

• In your storyboard, select your `UITabBarViewController`, and give it the class `TabViewController (on the right bar, 3rd section, custom class).

• In your `TabViewController.m` file, use this code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
    theView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:theView];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tabBar];
}
```

You can do whatever you want with `theView` before you add it to `self.view`, here I just create a 50x50 red square at the position (50, 50). The view will stay on top of everything else !

Run & have fun !

Comment: Careful, I forgot a line in my original post : *[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tabBar];* will keep the tab bar on top ! Otherwise, theView will be displayed over it.

Answer (score 1):

add that green banner on Window in appDelegate.

```
 [self.window addSubview:greenBannerView];
```

Comment: I need this view to be placed behind the tab bar, not on top of it.

Comment: **first** add bannerview  on window than tabbarcontroller.it will automatically goes behind tabbar.

Comment: you're right about that. But there must be a way to find this view and place it underneath it.